# Remove Custom Option "None"

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento. We've created a custom option. But whenever we choose "radial" it always displays a "None" option that we need to remove. I from what I understand this is pulling in some code from Magento Core.

This is the HTML that I need to edit:

```
<dt><label>Add a Display Case:</label></dt>
<dd class="last">
    <div class="input-box">
        <ul id="options-7-list" class="options-list"><li><input type="radio" id="options_7" class="radio product-custom-option" name="options[7]" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" value="" checked="checked" /><span class="label"><label for="options_7">None</label></span></li><li><input type="radio" class="radio  product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[7]" id="options_7_2" value="19"  price="45" /><span class="label"><label for="options_7_2">Acrylic Cube <span class="price-notice">+<span class="price">$45.00</span></span></label></span></li><li><input type="radio" class="radio  product-custom-option" onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()" name="options[7]" id="options_7_3" value="20"  price="75" /><span class="label"><label for="options_7_3">Lucite Case <span class="price-notice">+<span class="price">$75.00</span></span></label></span></li></ul>            </div>
</dd>
```

This is where I think it outputs....

```
<?php
class OptionExtended_Block_Product_View_Js extends  Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options
{
    protected $config = array();
    protected $thumbnailDirUrl = '';        
    protected $pickerImageDirUrl = '';

    protected function _construct()
    {   

        $children = array();        
        $sd = array();  
        $configValues = array();
        $inPreConfigured = $this->getProduct()->hasPreconfiguredValues();
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();                        
        $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();
        $filter = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');


        $options = $this->getProduct()->getOptions();

        foreach ($options as $option){
          if (!is_null($option->getLayout())){
              $id = (int) $option->getOptionId();

              if (!is_null($option->getRowId()))                    
                  $option_id_by_row_id[$option->getTemplateId()][(int) $option->getRowId()] = $id;

              $this->config[0][$id][0] = $option->getNote() != '' ? $filter->filter($option->getNote()) : '';   
              $this->config[0][$id][1] = $option->getLayout();                  
              $this->config[0][$id][2] = (int) $option->getPopup(); 

                if ($inPreConfigured){
                    $configValues[$id] = array();           
                    if (is_null($option->getRowId())){
                        $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $id);    
                        if (!is_null($configValue))
                            $configValues[$id] = (array) $configValue;                  
                    }
                } else { 
                    $sd[$option->getTemplateId()][$id] = explode(',', $option->getSelectedByDefault());
                }   


              if (!is_null($option->getValues())){                        
              foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {
                  $valueId = (int) $value->getOptionTypeId();
                  $this->prepareImages($value->getImage()); 

                  $rowId = (int) $value->getRowId();                            
                    $valueId_by_row_id[$value->getTemplateId()][$rowId] = $valueId;

                  $children[$value->getTemplateId()][$valueId] = explode(',', $value->getChildren());                       
                  $this->config[1][$valueId][0] = $value->getImage();                       
                  $this->config[1][$valueId][1] = $value->getDescription() != '' ? $filter->filter($value->getDescription()) : '';  
                  $this->config[1][$valueId][2] = array();  
                  $this->config[1][$valueId][3] = array();              
              }
              }     
            }                               
        }


        $options = Mage::getModel('optionextended/option')
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinNotes($storeId)               
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product_id);      
        foreach ($options as $option){
            $id = (int) $option->getOptionId();

            if (!is_null($option->getRowId()))                  
                $option_id_by_row_id['orig'][(int) $option->getRowId()] = $id;

            $this->config[0][$id][0] = $option->getNote() != '' ? $filter->filter($option->getNote()) : ''; 
            $this->config[0][$id][1] = $option->getLayout();                    
            $this->config[0][$id][2] = (int) $option->getPopup();   

            if ($inPreConfigured){
                $configValues[$id] = array();           
                if (is_null($option->getRowId())){
                    $configValue = $this->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $id);    
                    if (!is_null($configValue))
                        $configValues[$id] = (array) $configValue;                  
                }
            } else { 
                $sd['orig'][$id] = explode(',', $option->getSelectedByDefault());
            }           

        }   

        $values = Mage::getModel('optionextended/value')
            ->getCollection()
            ->joinDescriptions($storeId)                
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product_id);  
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $valueId = (int) $value->getOptionTypeId();
            $this->prepareImages($value->getImage());   

            $rowId = (int) $value->getRowId();                          
            $valueId_by_row_id['orig'][$rowId] = $valueId;

            $children['orig'][$valueId] = explode(',', $value->getChildren());                      
            $this->config[1][$valueId][0] = $value->getImage();                     
            $this->config[1][$valueId][1] = $value->getDescription() != '' ? $filter->filter($value->getDescription()) : '';    
            $this->config[1][$valueId][2] = array();    
            $this->config[1][$valueId][3] = array();                
        }   




        if ($inPreConfigured){
            foreach ($configValues as $optionId => $v){
                $this->config[0][$optionId][3] = array();           
                foreach($v as $valueId)
                        $this->config[0][$optionId][3][] = (int) $valueId;                              
            }       
        } else {        
            foreach ($sd as $templateId => $v){ 
                foreach ($v as $optionId => $vv){
                    $this->config[0][$optionId][3] = array();                   
                    foreach($vv as $rowId)
                        if ($rowId != '')
                            $this->config[0][$optionId][3][] = $valueId_by_row_id[$templateId][(int)$rowId];
                }
            }
        }


        foreach ($children as $templateId => $v){
          foreach ($v as $valueId => $vv){
              foreach ($vv as $rowId){
              if ($rowId != ''){
                    if (isset($option_id_by_row_id[$templateId][(int)$rowId]))
                        $this->config[1][$valueId][2][] = $option_id_by_row_id[$templateId][(int)$rowId];
                    else                
                        $this->config[1][$valueId][3][] = $valueId_by_row_id[$templateId][(int)$rowId]; 
                    }                   
              }
          }
        }       

    }



    public function getConfig()
    {   
        return Zend_Json::encode($this->config);
    }


    public function prepareImages($image)
    {   
        if ($image){
            $thumbnailUrl = $this->makeThumbnail($image);           
            $pickerImageUrl = $this->makePickerImage($image);
            if ($this->thumbnailDirUrl == ''){
                $this->thumbnailDirUrl = str_replace($image, '', $thumbnailUrl);                    
                $this->pickerImageDirUrl = str_replace($image, '', $pickerImageUrl);                                
            }   
        }
    }


    public function makeThumbnail($image)
    {   
        $thumbnailUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
            ->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image)
            ->keepFrame(true)
// Uncomment the following line to set Thumbnail RGB Background Color:
//          ->backgroundColor(array(246,246,246))   

// Set Thumbnail Size:          
            ->resize(100,100)
            ->__toString();
        return $thumbnailUrl;
    }       


    public function makePickerImage($image)
    {   
            $pickerImageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                ->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $image)
                ->keepFrame(false)
                ->resize(30,30)
                ->__toString();         
            return $pickerImageUrl;
        }   

    public function getThumbnailDirUrl()
    {           
            return $this->thumbnailDirUrl;
        }   


    public function getPickerImageDirUrl()
    {           
            return $this->pickerImageDirUrl;
        }

    public function getPlaceholderUrl()
    {
            return Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'small_image')->getPlaceholder());
        }   


    public function getProductBaseMediaUrl()
    {           
            return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaUrl();
        }   

    public function getInPreconfigured()
    {           
            return $this->getProduct()->hasPreconfiguredValues() ? 'true' : 'false';
        }   


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved by modifying the this file:
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php
modified lines 102-106

```
<?php
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
         //               $selectHtml .= '<li><input type="radio" id="options_'.$_option->getId().'" class="'.$class.' product-custom-option" name="options['.$_option->getId().']"' . ($this->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') . ' value="" checked="checked" /><span class="label"><label for="options_'.$_option->getId().'">' . $this->__('None') . '</label></span></li>';
                    }
                    break;
                case Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing something wrong.

[image: Magento Custom Options]

From this picture you can see that you can add your options which are then displayed in the frontend. Only these options will be displayed!

You do not need to make any changes in the Magento Core code to fix your problem.

If you still have problems please provide us with some screenshots and URL to your Magento web shop if possible.

Comment: I'm still having a problem. This code wasn't developed by me and I'm trying to troubleshoot the issues.

http://dev.hollywoodcollectibles.com/bill-russell-and-wilt-chamberlain-autographed-indoor-outdoor-basketball.html

[ScreenShot](http://demo.gunshowtrader.com/media/Screen-Shot-2014-10-08-at-2.06.48-PM.png)

Here it displays the 2 options but also a "None" before it.

Comment: You are using some custom module. I suggest you compare the core Magento code with the module code and see where this module "hardcodes" None option.
If you bought this module I suggest you contact their support.

Comment: That was my initial thought. I've go through each file individually doing searches for anything that might be related and none of it adds up.

It has to be on the output somewhere because it doesn't add it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an extension such as SWMS Option Image or similar to add extras like images to your custom options? This extension adds the None option.

You will need to go into the community folder and select your extension and edit the default.php and change "None" to "Standard" or something similar.

For SWMS Option image I changed:
/community/Swms/Optionimage/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select.php

```
<label for="options_'.$_option->getId().'">' . $this->__('Standard') . '</label>
```

Comment: I've been digging through the files to find something like that with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've got another solution. Edit the csv file. Mage_Catalog.csv. Add a row for None and add the word Standard to the next column.

Comment: I'm looking to remove that option completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, also what i have found if the field is not required magento will generate "None" option. Fast solution but not recommended is hide the option by css.